# pymsql not connecting to a database

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

I am trying to make software that works on a large number of people's computers by connecting to a login server. I have set up a MSQL server using 24hosting and added a database. I then tried to access the database using python, but it gives me the error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".

I need everyone who downloads this program to be able to connect, not just this computer.

This is probably something to do with my server, and not to do with code, but I will post the code below anyway.

```
from os import getenv
import pymysql

server = getenv("31.220.17.13")
user = getenv("shutdow1_user")
password = getenv("DSAEWQ321")

conn = pymysql.connect(server, user , password, "tempdp")

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT Host,User FROM user")
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run tcpdump or tshark host 31.220.17.13 to see what exactly happens.
Most likely TCP connection to mysql port is filtered (you would see RST replies on SYN send), or if you see that connection is closed by remote party after TCP session is established - that would be a sign of remote mysql server not configured properly to accept client connection for your IP/username/password/database.

Comment: Thanks for the help. How would I configure my SQL server to essentially allow anyone to access the database, not me adding them manually?

Comment: i am not sure you really want to grant everyone access to the database...
Usual practice is to grant restricted access for a certain user account and use that in the scripts your users are having access too (typical scenario - a script on a webserver using db user credentials with read- and/or append-only permissions). Anyway, this goes beyond the python topic, i suggest to read mySQL docs here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/account-management-sql.html.